# renderizar botão de acordo com o status

Tags: java, rich-faces

Estou utilizando o seguinte código para renderizar o meu botão para só aparecer com o status Aguardando aprovação mas não ocorre.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Enviar Solicitação" action="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.inserirSolicitacao}" 
        styleClass="espacoBotao" render="@form" rendered="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.peg.status.descricao  eq 'Aguardando Aprovação'}" />
```

Algém sabe o que há de errado com o código?

Comment: Não entendi o -1.. A descrição é exatamente `Aguardando Aprovação`? Talvez seja melhor você criar um método booleano no Managed Bean que retorna algo como `return "Aguardando Aprovação".equals(peg.getStatus().getDescricao())` e atribuir esse método no atributo `rendered` do botão

Comment: isso mesmo. vlw

Comment: Coloquei o comentário como resposta

Comment: Se acha que a minha resposta lhe ajudou, poderia marca-la como solução, por favor? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao invés de atribuir diretamente assim:

```
rendered="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.peg.status.descricao  eq 'Aguardando Aprovação'}"
```

Crie um método no Managed Bean que retorna exatamente isso.
Por exemplo:

```
@ManagedBean
public class SolicitacaoImpressaoBean {

    public boolean isAguardandoAprovacao() {
        return "Aguardando Aprovação".equals(peg.getStatus().getDescricao());
    }
}
```

E no XHTML faça:

```
rendered="#{solicitacaoImpressaoBean.aguardandoAprovacao()}"
```